# Databases for metabolic pathways of human disease

Tags: bioinformatics, genomics, biotechnology, systems-biology

Which databases contain the metabolic pathway of human diseases?
I have searched Metacyc and KEGG but didn't find the appropriate metabolic pathway.

Comment: What exactly are you searching for, and how specifically did KEGG and Metacyc fail to meet your requirements? Please [edit] your question with additional details so we can provide focused answers.

Comment: nearly any pathway can exhibit a disease if its damaged in the right way - disease is a dysfunction.  this is pretty difficult to answer in a way that makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

NCBI BioSystems help file contains a list of their sources:

http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/Structure/biosystems/docs/biosystems_help.html#SourceDatabases

Please specify what you need as stated in the comments as it is almost impossible to give you more (relevant) information then this.

Comment: I need the details of Ubiquitin/proteasome pathways which is responsible for cervical cancer from E6 and E7 oncoproteins?

Comment: I've been doing some research but I couldn't find exactly what you're looking for. I'm not a cancer research expert but you might find what you are looking for from this page: http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/biosystems/?term=DNA+repair+Ubiquitin
I'll let you know if I know more.

Comment: I need the step wise rections of ubiquitin/proteasome pathway. I have to calculate its parameters for COPASI.

Answer (score 0):

You can try Disgene package in Cytoscape.

Comment: please add some more detail if you can..